# JavaScript variable not adding up correctly when clicking on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement

I am making a website for a paintball team.  On the main page there is a small section to display the date of the next events.

*This is the relevant HTML code:*

```
    <aside class="aside-dates">

        <h1>PROCHAIN TOURNOI</h1>

        <h2 id="h2date">MIPL E4</h2>
        <h3 id="h3date">20 juillet 2013</h3>
        <h4 id="h4date">Mirabel, QC</h4>

        <div class="fleche gauche"></div>
        <div class="fleche droite"></div>

    </aside>
```

Using javascript I made a small function to change the content of the differant headers when the user clicks on either the left or right arrows. The goal here is for the user to see the upcoming events and can go back to the previous dates.

The date changes when I click on the right arrow one time but will stay at the second date if I click on the right arrow again. However, it will go back to the first date if I click on the left arrow.  I can go back an forth with the first and second date but it seems it won't register the additionnal value when going from second to third.

I know there must be a better way to do this but i'm lost, I also need to add other dates.

*Here is the JS:*

```
     var numero_date = 0;
     function clickDate(){
        if ( $(this).hasClass("gauche") ){
              numero_date--;
              if (numero_date <= 0){
                 alert(numero_date);
                 document.getElementById("h2date").innerHTML = "MIPL E4";
                 document.getElementById("h3date").innerHTML = "20 juillet 2013";
                 document.getElementById("h4date").innerHTML = "Mirabel, QC";
                 numero_date = 0;
              }
              else if(numero_date = 1){
                 alert(numero_date);
                 document.getElementById("h2date").innerHTML = "PSP";
                 document.getElementById("h3date").innerHTML = "16-18 août 2013";
                 document.getElementById("h4date").innerHTML = "Riverside, CA";
              }
              else if(numero_date = 2){
                 alert(numero_date);
                 document.getElementById("h2date").innerHTML = "MIPL Finales";
                 document.getElementById("h3date").innerHTML = "31 août 2013";
                 document.getElementById("h4date").innerHTML = "Mirabel, QC";
              }
        }
        else{
               numero_date++;
              if (numero_date <= 0){
                 alert(numero_date);
                 document.getElementById("h2date").innerHTML = "MIPL E4";
                 document.getElementById("h3date").innerHTML = "20 juillet 2013";
                 document.getElementById("h4date").innerHTML = "Mirabel, QC";
              }
              else if(numero_date = 1){
                 alert(numero_date);
                 document.getElementById("h2date").innerHTML = "PSP";
                 document.getElementById("h3date").innerHTML = "16-18 août 2013";
                 document.getElementById("h4date").innerHTML = "Riverside, CA";
              }
              else if(numero_date = 2){
                 alert(numero_date);
                 document.getElementById("h2date").innerHTML = "MIPL Finales";
                 document.getElementById("h3date").innerHTML = "31 août 2013";
                 document.getElementById("h4date").innerHTML = "Mirabel, QC";
              }
        }

     }
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is with your usage of assignment operator `=` instead of comparison operator `==`.

Change lines similar to the followng

```
else if (numero_date = 2) {
```

to

```
else if (numero_date == 2) {
```

Whenever it crosses `numero_date = 1` (where comparison is intended `numero_date == 1`), the value of that variable is set to 1 which never changes from there it always sets it to 1 in the if condition and never moves forward

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zq6Gt/)**

I am not clear on your reqs but instead of check ing for values, incrementing/decrementing the counters, you can probably use array functions like [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push),[pop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop),[shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift),[unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) to manage next/prev buttons and the cycling of data like this:

```
var arrEvents = []; //Set up the array of events
  arrEvents.push({
      'event': 'MIPL E4',
          'date': '20 juillet 2013',
          'venue': 'Mirabel, QC'
  },{
      'event': 'PSP',
          'date': '16-18 août 2013',
          'venue': 'Riverside, CA'
  },{
      'event': 'MIPL Finales',
          'date': '31 août 2013',
          'venue': 'Mirabel, QC'
  });

  function clickDate() {
      var obj;

      if ($(this).is(".gauche")) {
          obj = arrQuestions.shift(); //get the element from top
          arrQuestions.push(obj); //push it to the end
          obj = arrQuestions[0];

      } else {
          obj = arrQuestions.pop(); //get the element from end
          arrQuestions.unshift(obj); //ush it to the top
          obj = arrQuestions[arrQuestions.length-1];
      }

      console.log(JSON.stringify(arrQuestions));
      document.getElementById("h2date").innerHTML = obj.event;
      document.getElementById("h3date").innerHTML = obj.date;
      document.getElementById("h4date").innerHTML = obj.venue;


  }
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/NgJuN/)**

Comment: @MathieuDésilets if you think this resolved your issue please do remember to mark as answer.

Comment: @MathieuDésilets Just updated the fiddle and code for the second example.